# Read in the following table format: no tablehead, [date] colum1=xy colum2=abs colum4=iy

Tags: oracle, sas, proc-sql, datastep

i have a File with the data in the following format:

no tablehead

[date] colum1=xy colum2=abc colum4=xyz

[date] colum1=zz colum3=234 colum4=abc

The problem is, that not every dataset has all of the variables and they´re not seperated by like 2 tabs in that case. Therefore i need to read the file somehow with the columname in front of every datapoint. Im using a oracle database, but also can use SAS.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Is the date literally surrounded by square brackets?  Just use named input in SAS data step.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use [named input](https://documentation.sas.com/doc/en/pgmsascdc/9.4_3.5/lestmtsref/p1jjrvmzmybdeqn1gt8gj1r0ed0u.htm) mode.

```
data want;
  length date $10 column1-column4 $20;
  input date (column1-column4) (=);
cards;
[date] column1=xy column2=abc column4=xyz
[date] column1=zz column3=234 column4=abc
;
```

Results:

```
Obs     date     column1    column2    column3    column4

 1     [date]      xy         abc                   xyz
 2     [date]      zz                    234        abc
```